# Arquivo.CSS Somente pra uma DIV, É possível?

Tags: html, css

*Bom, provavelmente vou levar votos negativos por essa pergunta, então vou tentar explicar o máximo possível, peço que tentem entender e se não conseguirem, por favor perguntem.*

### **Situação**

Tenho uma página `.html` e nela, tenho meu arquivo `.css` *(usei style.css pra dar uma base na pergunta)*, nesse arquivo `.css` tenho minhas várias classes para todo o site, porém o problema vem quando preciso adicionar uma tabela de preço, mas essa tabela de preço tem varios elementos `.css` já existentes no arquivo `.css` e isso faz com que o layout simplesmente bugue.

### **Tá, mas o que quer?**

Gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de colocar algum tipo de `link rel` focado em uma div só, se eu conseguisse fazer isso, poderia usar o próprio arquivo `.css` da tabela sem bugar nada no site pois iria carregar as classes da tabela separado.

### **Resumo**

Preciso criar um tipo de `link rel` que funcione só pra uma div especifica.

### **O que já tentou?**

Mudar os nomes de todas as classes, porém ela possuí algumas classes que (não sei se vão me entender) simplesmente não pode ser mudada.

### **Cara isso tudo tá confuso**

Sim, eu sei, ta confuso até pra explicar, mas vamos lá mais uma vez, o arquivo `.css` da tabela, além de ser gigante, com centenas de classes, tem classes que são limpas, ou seja, `form`, `a` e sem prefixo.
A forma mais fácil de colocar essa tabela seria incorporando um arquivo `.css` focado em uma div por exemplo `div-prices`.

*Bom, é isso*
Peço desculpas pela confusão, tentei explicar da melhor forma, acredito que não tenha como fazer isso e que terei que me virar pra adicionar prefixos em todos os elementos, mas é sempre bom aprender mais não é mesmo?

Obrigado galera do Stack!

Comment: A pergunta é válida, mas a falta de códigos sim pode te causar uns downvotes.

Comment: Eu até pensei em colocar os códigos, porém a pergunta ia ficar extensa demais já que os códigos são grandes. Agradeço o conselho amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa disso. Crie um seletor específico para a tabela, como um `ID` único e referencie todos os estilos da tabela a partir deste seletor.

Exemplo:

```html
<table id="tabela-preco">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Preço (em R$/kg)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Açúcar</td>
            <td> 1,80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arroz Tipo 1</td>
            <td> 10,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Feijão</td>
            <td> 4,50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"> Consulta: 02/04/2016</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Bem, a partir do seletor `ID` no elemento-pai, você pode selecionar qualquer elemento da tabela e somente dentro dela, se quiser.

```css
#tabela-preco {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#tabela-preco thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#tabela-preco thead tr th {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

/* mais formatacões para a tabela podem ser inseridas */
```

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, coisa tão simples e eu quebrando a cabeça haha, valeu amigo agradeço a salvação.